# Über das Adjektiv "papiergeworden"

Tags: meaning

> Der Kalender ist die **papiergewordene** Abhängigkeit, das Abbild eines durchchoreographierten Lebens, dem jede Spontaneität verlorengegangen ist.

Wo kommt das Wort her und was bedeutet es? Das Verb "papierwerden" kann ich nirgends finde, das Wort selbst scheint nicht besonders geläufig zu sein.

Comment: Das ist eine Wortbildung analog zu *fleischgeworden*.

Comment: Es ist ein Auszug aus dieser schwachsinnigen Abhandlung:
https://www.jetzt.de/sexkritik/deine-meine-unsere-termine-574890

Comment: Na, so schwer ist das aber nicht. Was könnte das Wort wohl bedeuten? Zähle bitte auf, was dir bisher dazu eingefallen ist, und dann sagen wir dir, was von deiner Liste richtig ist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hier ist wie oft das Ganze die Summe seiner Einzelteile:

Papier - offensichtlich

geworden - das Partizip Perfekt von *werden*

Es handelt sich also um die Eigenschaft eines Dinges, "zu Papier geworden" zu sein. Die Konstruktion ist eine Imitation der Wortbildung *fleischgeworden*, das in der christlichen Glaubenswelt so viel wie "personifiziert" bedeutet.

Answer (score 2):

Du kannst das Wort **papierwerden* nicht finden, weil es das nicht gibt. Aber der Reihe nach.

Die deutsche Sprache kennt sehr viele zusammengesetzte Wörter. Üblicherweise werden Wörter, die aus Einzelteilen zusammengesetzt sind, auch zusammengeschrieben; siehe zum Beispiel *Papierkranich* (ein Kranich aus Papier). Dein Wort *papiergeworden* besteht aus den Bestandteilen *Papier* und *geworden;* letzteres ist das Partizip Perfekt des Verbs *werden.* Daraus kann man die Bedeutung ableiten: Etwas ist zu Papier geworden.

Ob man ein Wort auch tatsächlich zusammenschreiben darf, hängt von der Wortart ab – nicht nur der Wortart des Produkts sondern auch der Wortarten der Bestandteile. Im Falle von *papiergeworden* in deinem Beispiel handelt es sich um ein Adjektiv, das aus dem Partizip eines Verbs und einem Substantiv gebildet wurde. Diese kann man – wie das Beispiel zeigt – zusammenschreiben.

Wenn du vom Adjektiv zurück zu einem entsprechenden Verb willst, ändern sich die Voraussetzungen. Denn bei Zusammensetzungen gehen regelmäßig Präpositionen und andere Partikeln verloren. In beiden Beispielen ist das so, der Kranich besteht **aus** Papier und die Abhängingkeit wird **zu** Papier. Hat man eine solche Konstruktion, die einer Präposition bedarf, kann das Verb *nicht* zusammengeschrieben werden. Es kann also nur heißen: *zu Papier werden.*

Man könnte also den Gedanken im weitesten Sinne auch anders ausdrücken, indem man sagt:

> Unsere Abhängigkeit ist zu Papier geworden und als Kalender zurückgekehrt.

Falsch wäre, hier *Papier* und *geworden* zusammenzuschreiben, selbst wenn man das *zu* weglässt.

Answer (score 1):

Manchmal hilft es einfach, selbst nachzudenken bevor man andere fragt. Was könnte der Satz

> Der Kalender ist die papiergewordene Abhängigkeit.

wohl bedeuten?

Ich liste hier mal ein paar Möglichkeiten auf, nur eine davon ist richtig:

- Der Kalender ist die zu Papier gewordene Abhängigkeit.

<sup>*(Tut mir leid, dass die Liste so kurz geraten ist, aber mehr plausible Möglichkeiten sind mir nicht eingefallen)*</sup>

Comment: Wie kann aber eine Abhängigkeit zu Papier werden? Die Frage hört sich zwar etwas dämlich an, aber auf meine Muttersprache ist solch einer Satz schlicht unmöglich.

Comment: Du solltest aufhören in deiner Muttersprache zu denken wenn du Deutsch sprichst. Denke immer in der Sprache, die du sprichst.

Comment: Also ich finde die Antwort nicht *besser*, aber wesentlich *passender* als meine. Danke Hubert, +1